# Dell ME4084 slow speed with Intel E810 25G in Hyper-V Failover using iSCSI

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, iscsi, dell-powervault

**PLEASE READ 3RD EDIT BELOW**

I am currently trying to figure out why the following server setup is getting me only slow speeds on SMB copys.
The setup is the following:

- 2x Dell PowerEdge R7525 each with three Intel 25G 2P E810-XXV
- 1x Dell ME4084 Storage
- 1x Switch Dell S5248F-ON

VLAN 97 is used to connect to the rest of the network and VLAN13 and VLAN14 is iSCSI exclusive.

The Servers are running **Windows Server 2022 Datacenter with Hyper-V Failover cluster**. The Dell ME4084 Storage is connected via iSCSI using VLANs and MPIO enabled in windows. Firmware and Software are on latest versions.

So after testing and modifying almost all settings on the Intel NICs I was able to get constant 2-2,5GB/s file transfer between the servers itself. I think the most important settings are SR-IOV and RDMA enabled and send and receive buffers set to maximum (4096). So direct traffic between servers is no problem anymore.

The Problem is data transfer to the storage, it is way too slow. I only get 300-500 MB/s when reading/writing to the Storage from either server, interestingly one server is around 500 MB/s the other sometimes drops to 180 MB/s and most of the time stays around 200 MB/s.
I already tried around with all network parameters and also enabled iSCSI detection and QoS on the switch (altough not sure if currently configured, but it detects iSCSI packages) but still no success. I don't know how to get the full NIC speed, I know the storage should be way faster, it has 60% SSDs and even with HDDs it should get around 1 GB/s according to Dell benchmarks.

Is there anything I could have misconfigured or do I need Datacenter bridging or something like that? Is the switch the problem or maybe a iSCSI configuration issue within windows?

EDIT:
<s>This is the IP configuration:</s>

ServerA:

- Intel E810 NIC1: 10.20.30.10/24 (main network) (vlan97 tag set by switch)
- Intel E810 NIC2: 172.16.10.10/24 and 172.16.11.10/24 (iSCSI network) with VLAN13 tag set in network device settings

ServerB:

- Intel E810 NIC1: 10.20.30.11/24 (main network) (vlan97 tag set by switch)
- Intel E810 NIC2: 172.16.10.11/24 and 172.16.11.11/24 (iSCSI network) with VLAN13 tag set in network device settings

ME4084:

- ControllerA - Port1: 172.16.10.2
- ControllerA - Port2: 172.16.11.3
- ControllerA - Port3: 172.16.10.4
- ControllerA - Port4: 172.16.11.5
- 
- ControllerB - Port1: 172.16.10.6
- ControllerB - Port2: 172.16.11.7
- ControllerB - Port3: 172.16.10.8
- ControllerB - Port4: 172.16.11.9

**EDIT 2:**

After experimenting around a bit more I found out that if I mount my storage volume directly on one Server the speed is around 900 MB/s to around 1,3 GB/s (quite unstable but way faster). As soon as I add the volume to my failovercluster as ClusterStorage the speed drops to 500-600 MB/s, so maybe the problem lies somewhere else?

**EDIT 3:**

According to the feedback here, I added a second Intel E810 Network card to the servers. The network now looks like the following:

[image: New Network layout]

**I know with this layout we don't have redundancy, we WILL add a second switch after solving the speed problems!**

So after reading through a lot of articles I configured the network as this: The two iSCSI NICs are configured with intel Storage Profile, no SR-IOV, no VM-Switch, VLAN tags added by switch.
The LAN NIC is configured with a Hyper-V Switch with SR-IOV and RDMA, VLAN tags added by switch.
So as recommended by a lot of people the iSCSI NICs are without Hyper-V switch and without teaming etc.

So because the Dell ME4 Series storages only support max 128 TiB volume size and we wanted a bigger storage, we split the Pool into 3 volumes and in Windows created a Cluster Storage Pool and volume over the 3 storage volumes (no provisioning or mirror) to get a total size of around 350 TiB. This storage is then added as cluster shared volume and here we added a Cluster Role with Scale-Out File Storage (SoFS). On This failover cluster are also running a few VMs with SR-IOV enabled, VHDX also stored on the Cluster shared volume. So the problem is still the speed. It's really inconsistent and maxes out around 500-600 MB/s and sometimes drop below 200 MB/s. I know the storage can reach more since after some tests with different configurations I managed to reach around 2GB/s with it, but not with all the failover cluster and pooling stuff.
So I am not sure if the problem lies somewhere in the failover stuff or Cluster Storage Pool etc.; but after a quick call with Dell they told us that storage Pool is the best way to avoid the 128 TiB limit on the ME4 series storage. Did we mess up? What would be the best solution to reach a BIG (300TB+) SMB Storage and also have VM's with failover clustering?

Comment: Might it help to add another NIC and split iSCSI to seperate lanes? Currently one NIC is connected to 10.20.30.0/24 network and the other is using two IPs for iSCSI (172.16.10.0 and 172.16.11.0)

Comment: It looks like the problem lies somewhere in the switch configuration regarding DCB and iscsi priority settings etc. But I can't get my head around the config, I don't know how to setup the switch to do proper DCBx for iScsi

Comment: Do you really only have one switch? And your links aren't configured as trunks? Is that right?

Comment: Yes thats right, I currently have jumbo frames on on switch and NICs and flowcontrol on on switch and NICs.

Comment: That just seems a little...amateur is all

Comment: If possible could you boot a Linux live cd and mount the iscsi disks that way and see what the performance is. I just want to see if there is a limit in hyper-v or Windows

Comment: And can you run the best practice analyzer if possible `Get-BPAmodel | Invoke-BPAmodel`

Comment: Good idea with the linux live cd, I will try this

Answer (score 2):

You haven't detailed your IP configuration - the PowerVault devices like a 1:1 mapping from host to controller ports. If you've got just a single subnet, each host port connects to each controller port in a n:m fashion - that might cause your bad performance.

Instead, use a dedicated subnet for each controller port pair, e.g. 172.16.10.0/24 for controller ports A1, B1 and host NIC 1, and 172.16.11.0/24 for A2, B2 and host NIC 2.

Since your host ports are twice as fast as the ME4 ones, you could use just two subnets with controller ports A1, B1, A2, B2, host NIC 1, and the other with A3, B3, A4, B4, host NIC 2.

However, in case there could be future hosts with 10G NICs, I would stick with four subnets and bind IP addresses from two of the subnets to each 25G NIC.

Watch out for non-preferred paths - accessing a disk group through the wrong controller pulls the LUN over and really hurts performance. If ALUA doesn't work correctly (check in Storage Manager or in the logs) you'll have to assemble the preferred paths manually which ain't fun in Windows.

And of course, your storage performance hangs on your disks - obviously SSDs perform best, then 15k disks, 10k, ... For best performance with a given set of disks, always use a power of two plus the redundant drives in a RAID set, e.g. RAID 6 with 6, 10 or 18 drives. More rotating spindles in an array are generally faster but beware of a rebuild with large disks.

As a side note, your setup isn't redundant with a single switch. You should have two switches with half of the iSCSI subnets each. Just in case you should use two VLANs, one for each switch.

Comment: "Instead, use a dedicated subnet for each controller port pair, e.g. 172.16.10.0/24 for controller ports A1, B1 and host NIC 1, and 172.16.11.0/24 for A2, B2 and host NIC 2." Thats how its connected, altough through the switch. Port A1, B1, A2, B2 are subnet 172.16.10.0/24 and Port A3, B3, A4, B4 are 172.16.11.0/24.

Since I only have two NICs per server I put one of the NICs in both subnets, might this be the problem? (see my comment on my question)

Comment: Well, there's no failover with a single NIC. I'd add another, perhaps only a 10G for LAN connectivity.

Comment: Yes I know but currently I am concentrating on the speed problems.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't put this in a comment. But I have a PowerShell script to run the best practice analyzer. Maybe it finds a misconfig

```
# Import the BestPractices module
Import-Module BestPractices

# Get BPA models and invoke them
$models = Get-BPAmodel
foreach ($model in $models) {
    try {
        $results = Invoke-BPAmodel -Model $model
        $bpaResults = Get-BpaResult -Model $model
        Write-Host "Results for $($model.Name):"
        Write-Host $bpaResults
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error invoking $($model.Name): $_"
    }
}
```